# Where have I erred in proving $\sum_{k=0}^\infty ar^k = {a\over 1-r}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, geometric-series

I'm familiar with the infinite geometric series, its convergence conditions, and the formula for the value of convergence:

$$S_{\infty} = {a\over 1-r}\quad |r| < 1$$

...for an infinite geometric series with start term $a$ and common ratio $r$.

I've seen this proven a few different ways, and recently devised my own simple proof founded in simple algebraic manipulations. It is intuitively clear to me that $|r|<1$ is a necessary condition for convergence. However, in the below proof, I seem to find that the value of convergence is $a/(1-r)$ *without* requiring $|r|<1$ (only $r\neq 1$ seems to be necessary).

Have I erred somewhere? Where should the convergence condition come into play?

> **Proof.**
> Consider the sum: \begin{align} \sum_{k=0}^\infty ar^k  &= ar^0 + ar^1
>  + ar^2 + \cdots \\ & = a + ar + ar^2 + \cdots \\ & = a(1 + r + r^2 + \cdots) \end{align}
>
> Now, consider the product:
>
> $$(1-r)(1 + r + r^2 + \cdots)$$
>
> \begin{align} \require{cancel} & = (1 + \cancel{r} + \cancel{r^2} +
>  \cdots) + (\cancel{-r} - \cancel{r^2} - \cdots) \\ & = 1 \end{align}
>
> Hence:
>
> $${1\over 1-r} = (1+r+r^2+\cdots)\quad r\neq 1$$
>
> Therefore:
>
> $${a\over 1-r} = a(1 + r + r^2+\cdots) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty ar^k\quad r\neq 1$$

Comment: peek-a-boo's answer gives the right way to go about things. I'll add that your demonstration requires convergence in the line where you cancel out terms, because you rely implicitly on the ability to reorder the terms.

Comment: @BrianTung convergence alone doesn't allow for reordering. That cancelation step merely uses the fact that for convergent series, the sum of series is series of the sum

Comment: Of course for this particular series the places it does converge, it also converges absolutely, so everything works out, but it's good to keep in mind that this extra step is unnecessary.

Comment: @peek-a-boo: No, but lack of convergence means it cannot be relied upon.

Comment: @BrianTung OP's whole argument is based on the premise (even though it's not explicitly stated) that $r$ is a number such that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}r^k$ converges. And with this assumption, the justification provided for $(1-r)(1+r+r^2+\dots)=1$ uses only basic facts about convergent sums, and it's completely correct (and doesn't invoke anything about reordering).

Comment: @peek-a-boo: I may be misreading OP, but they seem to be wondering why their quoted demonstration seems to work without regard for convergence. That is to say, they *expect* to need convergence, but don't see that it's actually used. I'm pointing out that if the series were *not* convergent, they could not rely on the cancellation. Certainly none of the other manipulations depend crucially on convergence (though of course then the sum is not defined).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you showed is that "**if the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}ar^k$ converges** and $r\neq 1$ then $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}ar^k=\frac{a}{1-r}$". And you certainly gave a correct proof of this fact, because by assuming the series converges, all the manipulations can be justified.

However, you haven't answered the question of when the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}ar^k$ converges. So, just emphasizing again: you gave a correct proof, but it's a proof of a completely different question. You haven't answered the question "for what values of $r$ does the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}ar^k$ converge"?

The full answer is

- If $a=0$, the sum clearly converges for all values of $r$.
- If $a\neq 0$, the sum converges if and only if $|r|<1$.

The proof of this relies on the observation that for $r\neq 1$, $\sum_{k=0}^nr^k=\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$. The limit of this as $n\to\infty$ exists in $\Bbb{R}$ if and only if $|r|<1$. The advantage of this approach is that we're literally using the definition of a series as a limit of partial sums, so it makes it very obvious where the limiting condition occurs and what restrictions have to be placed on $r$.